# Team Foundation Server in Windows VIsta

Tags: tfs, windows-vista

Will Team Foundation Server work in Windows Vista.

Comment: (see comment on Dove's answer)

Comment: @BALAMURUGAN i'll put you're strange editing and downvoting down to inexperience.  You can have Tfs explorer on windows Vista no problem but Vista is not a supported platform for the actual server.  That is, you could connect to a Tfs project from your Vista machine but you couldn't host one there.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific.  First off if you're working with beta softare (VS 2010), you should be aware of potential issues.

Not sure I get what you mean by "I like to have Foundation Server".  You could try connecting to an open source project on codeplex to see if you can.

Comment: Comment and downvote (fixed) is inappropriate; the original question mentioned VS2010.